# Do I need to remortgage to get rid of PMI with a new appraisal?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, pmi, appraisal

I asked [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/do-i-need-to-remortgage-to-get-rid-of-pmi) about whether I need to re-apply for my mortgage in order to not have to pay private mortgage insurance anymore. All answers mentioned that this is not necessary.

However, I'm wondering if the answers apply only to the original appraised value. In other words, do I need to remortgage if I appraise my house again, and the house is appraised at a higher value and therefore I end up owning a higher percentage of the home than before? Can lenders request me to apply for a new mortgage in order to get rid of PMI based on a new appraisal?

Comment: This question has already  been answered in the comments following your previous question: once you are down to 80% _and your account is in good standing_ (e.g. no currently delinquent payments; all previous payments made in timely fashion) _and_ you have a new _acceptable-to-lender_ appraisal showing that property has not decreased in value_, then you can ask for PMI to be removed, and _if_ the lender declines, you can choose to remortgage if you wish. You will be out the closing costs of the new mortgage and the new lender may demand another appraisal if previous one is deemed to be too old.

Comment: I don't see any comment about "having a new acceptable-to-lender appraisal", which is exactly the difference between my previous question and this one.